# Can't upgrade JHipster from 5.0.1 to 5.1.0

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to generate new app in empty folder.

```
$ jhipster
Using JHipster version installed globally
Running default command
Executing jhipster:app
Options: 


        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????
        ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????
  ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????
  ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????
   ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???

                            https://www.jhipster.tech

Welcome to JHipster v5.0.1
Application files will be generated in folder: /home/eclipse-workspace/jhtest
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Documentation for creating an application is at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/
  If you find JHipster useful, consider sponsoring the project at https://opencollective.com/generator-jhipster
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

 ______________________________________________________________________________

  JHipster update available: 5.1.0 (current: 5.0.1)

  Run yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster to update.
```

So I canceled this and try:

```
$ yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster
yarn global v1.7.0
error Outdated lockfile. Please run `yarn install` and try again.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

Then:

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.7.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.06s.
```

It creates node_modules folder and yarn.lock file but

```
$ yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster
```

generates error Outdated lockfile as above.
What I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you mix NPM and Yarn global packages.

To fix, remove from both npm and yarn:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
yarn global remove generator-jhipster
```

Then install with one or the other:

```
yarn global add generator-jhipster
```

Comment: When following these commands I get an error as follows: error generator-jhipster@5.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8.10.0".

Comment: After upgrading nodejs to 8.11.3, jhipster has now been upgraded to 5.1.0